# Iterating variable through a string

Tags: python, loops, iterator, arcgis

I am working with ArcGIS, but this should be applicable to any situation with an iterator and a string. I have pairs of images which I want to run through this function, which have the same name and then increasing numbers within parenthesis. I am trying to use an iterator which would update the number on each loop, so the process would run each loop on 2 different images.

Here is my code:

```
def my_filter(iterable):
    result=[]
    for i in iterable:
        result.append(i)
        if i==400:
            continue
        yield result
        result=[]

idx = iter(range(0, 400))

for i in my_filter(idx):
    arcpy.management.CompositeBands("'Visual ("[i]").tif';'Thermal ("[i]").tif'",
        r"C:\Users\calma\Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\RasterMerge\RasterMerge.gdb\Multi"[i])
}
```

Essentially, is there a way for me to put the `i`s in this string that would recognize it as a part of the string and get the correct photo?

Here is what it normally looks like:

```
arcpy.management.CompositeBands("'Visual (23).tif';'Thermal (23).tif'", r"C:\Users\calma\Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\RasterMerge\RasterMerge.gdb\Multi23")
```

Comment: Can you provide some samples of the output you expect for a few iterations through the main for loop?

Answer (score 1):

You mean like?

```
arcpy.management.CompositeBands(f"'Visual ("{i}").tif';'Thermal ("{i}").tif'",
    f"C:\Users\calma\Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\RasterMerge\RasterMerge.gdb\Multi{i}")
```

Comment: This might be the right syntax, but the interpreter in ArcGIS is throwing an error message at this.                        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
                  SyntaxError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
File C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\ast.py, in parse:
Line 35:    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)

SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 13)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: I have a feeling it is the second line, MULTI{i} probably needs to be a legit filename